# Pandas - count of unique columns with sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  cost 
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10     2       
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10     5       
2  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15     2       
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15     1       
4  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15     7       
5  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3     2       
6  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10     4   
7  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10     4
```

I wanted to find the count of every unique combination for columns x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, ID and get the sum of those counts and apply the value found in the cost column to get a total sum per unique combination found.

The end result hopefully will look like this:

```
   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID   count sum
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93     lightz  10       2   7      
1  354  abc  94mmm4k             heavy  15       2   3      
2  354  abc  94mmm4k   455h             15       1   7
3  354  abc  94mmm4k             super   3       1   2
4  354  abc  94mmm4k    53g             10       2   8
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: I have tried and researched the topic but I do not put those details, my apologies about my etiquette. I did not see anything wrong with my approach but I see that it's a problem with you. I will work to add more context to what I have attempted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `groupby` with `agg`

```
s=df.groupby(['x_1','x_2','x_3','x_4','x_5','ID'],as_index=False)['cost'].agg(['count','sum'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! when I run this query it does not look like its taking into account the combinations of rows that might be empty. Is there anything else we can add to this so the empty cells are accounted for and drive up the unique combination count?

Comment: @Aldo that is empty or NaN if NaN df.fillna('',inplace=True)

Comment: right, they are not empty.. my apologies, they are set to none.

Comment: @Aldo do `df.fillna('',inplace=True)` before above